# Bootstrap contextual table based off certain variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I set up a table that grabs information from a Mysql database and displays it quit nicely. However i would like the table "row" to change colors based off the aging of the account? Any simple easy ways of achieving this?

**Home.php**

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-responsive">
                        <tr class="header">
                            <td>Rep</td>
                            <td>Date</td>
                            <td>Name</td>
                            <td>P_O</td>
                            <td>Due Date</td>
                            <td>Terms</td>
                            <td>Aging</td>
                            <td>Open Balance</td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php 
                            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

                                $className ="";
                                if ($row['Aging'] >= 45)
                                {
                                    $className="clsRedRow";
                                }
                                else if($row['Aging'] >= 25 && $row['Aging'] <= 44)
                                {
                                    $className="clsYellowRow";
                                }

                                echo "<tr class='$className'>";
                                echo "<td>".$row[Rep]."</td>";
                                echo "<td>".$row[Date]."</td>";
                                echo "<td>".$row[Name]."</td>";
                                echo "<td>".$row[P_O]."</td>";
                                echo "<td>".$row[Due_Date]."</td>";
                                echo "<td>".$row[Terms]."</td>";
                                echo "<td>".$row[Aging]."</td>";
                                echo "<td>".$row[Open_Balance]."</td>";
                            }
                        ?>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: I think your values need quotes around the array elements, like `$row['Rep']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a class inline to the `<tr>` elements. Something like this:

```
<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
{
    $className = "";
    if ($row['Aging'] < 50) 
    {
        $className = "clsRedRow";
    } 
    else
    {
        $className = "clsGreenRow";
    }
    echo "<tr class='$className'>";
    echo "<td>" . $row[Rep] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row[Date] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row[Name] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row[P_O] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row[Due_Date] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row[Terms] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row[Aging] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row[Open_Balance] . "</td>";
}
?>
```

Then, you'd need to have the proper styles set up in the HTML document (above the PHP script, not sure where the rest of your styles are set):

```
<style>
  .clsRedRow{ background-color: red; }
  .clsGreenRow{ background-color: green; }
</style>
```

Comment: that for some reason seems to skip over some rows?

Comment: It all depends on how you're testing `$row['Aging']` and assigning different classes. Update your original question with your new code and we can take a look.

Comment: So there are rows that won't be assigned a class (those with `Aging < 25`). Is this how you want it to work? Which rows are being skipped? Have you set your `<style>` section properly for `.clsRedRow` and `.clsYellowRow`?

Comment: yes this is how i want it to work, it dome reason had to with the .clasYellowRow. I changed them out to "danger"(red) and "warning"(yellow) and it works great now! thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I would probably add a class to the aging cells, and then iterate over them and check the value in a jQuery function to apply your styling based on the range the number falls in.

```
$("#some-table .aging").each(function() {
  var age = $(this).html();
  if (age <= 2) {
    $(this).parent().css({"background-color" : "blue"});
  } else if (age <= 5) {
    $(this).parent().css({"background-color" : "yellow"});
  } else if (age <= 8) {
    $(this).parent().css({"background-color" : "red"});
  }
});
```

Like this: http://codepen.io/jonathanrbowman/pen/epVBox

Comment: where would you suggest i put the JS? ad the end of the page or within the PHP

Comment: It's really up to you and how you have everything organized. I don't know anything about your project, but I'd probably have a separate js file linked at the end of the body that had all of my functions related to whatever this table is. I tend to prefer using multiple js files, each with a dedicated purpose to make it easier to find things as a project grows.